# How to make my table cells to wrap inside the parent container

Tags: html, css

I want my table cells to fit inside the container. In other words, I want my cells to wrap around the parent container. For some reason, the keep going and going, no wrapping whatsoever...

JSFIDDLE

https://jsfiddle.net/yLfpjqum/

HTML

```
<h1>TEST TABLE</h1>

<div class="colAB">
  <div>
    <p>menu goes here...</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="table">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="cell"><img src="" width="125" height="125" alt=""></div>
        <div class="cell"><img src="" width="125" height="125" alt=""></div>
        <div class="cell"><img src="" width="125" height="125" alt=""></div>
        <div class="cell"><img src="" width="125" height="125" alt=""></div>
        <div class="cell"><img src="" width="125" height="125" alt=""></div>
        <div class="cell"><img src="" width="125" height="125" alt=""></div>
        <div class="cell"><img src="" width="125" height="125" alt=""></div>
        <div class="cell"><img src="" width="125" height="125" alt=""></div>
        <div class="cell"><img src="" width="125" height="125" alt=""></div>
        <div class="cell"><img src="" width="125" height="125" alt=""></div>
        <div class="cell"><img src="" width="125" height="125" alt=""></div>
        <div class="cell"><img src="" width="125" height="125" alt=""></div>
        <div class="cell"><img src="" width="125" height="125" alt=""></div>
        <div class="cell"><img src="" width="125" height="125" alt=""></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.table {
  display: table;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
}

.colAB {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: red;
}

.colAB > div:nth-child(1) {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: black;
}

.colAB > div:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: `I want my cells to wrap around the parent container`? You want a cell to wrap around a row? This really has no sense, can you create an image to explain?

Comment: @skobaljic exactly... no image but check the jsfiddle. The cells(therefore row) must wrap around the yellow container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the expected behavior, and even fits with your class names: everything in a "row" should be in one row.

But it's easy to get the effect you're going for: just add `float:left` to the cells:

```css
.cell {
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

(Note that I've left out your `display` styles and your `row`, since they aren't a necessary part of the answer)

Comment: henry: floating left did it! I thought it was normal behavior for a cell to wrap around the row and parent container.. i guess not. Thanks